# Storing Field Values With Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

I have a web app that I created to ease submitting sites to directories, but I have a bit of an issue. Whenever I close the window, the fields go blank and the checkboxes get unchecked. What I've been doing to work around this is just hard coding the site information every time and adding a checked value to the checkboxes in the HTML before closing the page.

What I would like to do is use local storage to store the value of these fields, with "save" and "clear" buttons. <strike>Unfortunately every time I've looked at cookies, my head explodes.</strike> I'm just using 7 text fields with separate names, and 40 checkboxes with separate names. I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

http://bearce.me/seo/

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are not a good mechanism for storing form information, not least because they can be intercepted by anyone between the server and browser (Man in the middle attack).

Another reason they are not suitable is that they are not designed to hold large amounts of data, so if the user has entered a large amount of text, it will be lost.

Think about using [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) - this is what it is for.

Comment: Elaborating on this post; Cookies are designed to store a reference to something that HOLDS the data (on the server). Such as some unique ID, or String, that you can parse, and then retrieve relevant data based upon. Local Storage is a great solution injunction with some fallback functionality. +1.

Comment: Ah, updated to reference Local Storage instead. This is just a personal tool and the data will generally not be needed to be stored for more than a day (plus it's not sensitive information in any way, just meta data from sites), but if you think Local Storage is better than that's fine by me.